# Vibrate when hold down button

Tags: android, button, vibration, android-vibration

I am making an app where the user holds down a button to make the phone vibrate and i'm not sure how to make it so only when the button is being held down it vibrates, my code so far is.

```
package one.two.bn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



    public class Vb extends Activity {
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private Button button1;
        private Vibrator vibrator;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);    
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v==button1){ 
                vibrator.vibrate(300000);           
        }
    }
```

If any on can help thanks a lot.

Comment: Aren't you missing a close parenthesis after setOnClickListener? Where do you close it?

Answer (score 70):

Try this code

```
Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ;
```

Then in the `OnClickListener` of your button:

```
vibe.vibrate(50); // 50 is time in ms
```

And dont forget you need to add the permission to the manifest (after the `</application>` tag):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

I also agree with Tim, because `onTouchListener` is called before on click so it is give best output for your app.

Answer (score 45):

If you need the long-press-feedback vibration just like ActionMode or ContextMenu do,

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Use an `OnTouchListener()` instead of `onClick()`.
Inside the listener when `MotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` you will call `vibrator.start(some arbitrarily large number here perhaps 1 minute or more)`
And when `getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` call `vibrator.cancel().`
That way it will start vibrating when you press down and stop when you lift up.

Answer (score 1):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  [...]
public void onClick(View v) {
  if(v==button1){ // <- Don't need that...
    // Do Stuff...
  }
}});
```

If you use an inner Class for the 'onClickListener', you don't need to check if the View is the Button, because only the Button can trigger that 'onClick'-method.

Also, if you want the phone to vibrate as long as you hold down the Button, use the ['onLongClick'-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add permissions for vibration in manifest file.